# PCIe port backwards compatibility

Tags: compatibility, pci-express

Are PCIe generations backwards compatible?  And will a port with N channels support a device with less than N channels?

For instance, supposing I had a motherboard with a PCIe 3.0 x16 port.  Would something that required a PCIe 2.0 x1 port be compatible with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking yes. Given a PCIe 3.0 x16 slot, your PCIe 1.x and 2.x cards will be compatible. And yes, a x16 slot will support x16, x8, x4, x2, x1 cards.

Have a look at this:

https://www.pcisig.com/news_room/faqs/pcie3.0_faq/#EQ6

Comment: The only reason why I'm saying *generally yes* is because, while the PCIe specifications promise backwards compatibility, you might still find that certain implementations of the specification break that compatibility. However in my experience older PCIe cards have *always* worked in newer slots.